# React error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') #react

Tags: reactjs

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([ ]);
  const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setNewTask(event.target.value);
  }

  const handleAdd = () => {
    const task = {
      id: tasks.length === 0 ? 1 : tasks[tasks.length-1].id +1,
      name: newTask
      
    }

    setTasks(...tasks, task)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">

     <div className='add-task'>
      <input placeholder='What are you going to do today?' onChange={handleChange}></input>
      <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add Task</button>
     </div>
       
        
     <div className='tasks-list'>  
     
     </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the error I get. Please help me!
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emH2j.png)...................................................................

............................................ #react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing 2 arguments to `setTasks` function but it should receive only 1 parameter: the next state or the updater function.

Change `setTasks(...tasks, task)` to `setTasks(prevTasks => [...prevTasks, task])`